# Images inside table are showing outside the table

Tags: css, image, html-table

I want 4 gray blocks next to the fire truck image, but no matter how I place them in a table, they show up lower as if there is 200px of padding above them. I can't figure out why they keep moving.I want them top aligned, and adding a vertical align didn't help.

```
<table width="1000" border="0" height="322">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="/Images/Monroe_Fire_Department_Website_Banner_03.jpg"></td>
      <td class="work"><img src="/Images/Banner-Nav-Background-Gray_03.jpg">
      <img src="/Images/Banner-Nav-Background-Gray_03.jpg">
      <img src="/Images/Banner-Nav-Background-Gray_03.jpg">
      <img src="/Images/Banner-Nav-Background-Gray_03.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Feel free to take a look at the example/source code with the link below.

http://monroefiredepartment.businesscatalyst.com/test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending CSS looks like `vertical-align: baseline` being applied to all elements on the page.  If you inspect the `<td>` element that contains the four grey blocks, and uncheck `vertical-align: baseline`, then the blocks shift upwards and align with the top of the fire truck image.

I think that you can safely remove this from the stylesheet, as it doesn't appear to affect any other elements on the page.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table width="1000" border="0" height="322">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="/Images/Monroe_Fire_Department_Website_Banner_03.jpg"></td>
      <td valign="top" style="
    float: left;
"><img src="/Images/Banner-Nav-Background-Gray_03.jpg">
      <img src="/Images/Banner-Nav-Background-Gray_03.jpg">
      <img src="/Images/Banner-Nav-Background-Gray_03.jpg">
      <img src="/Images/Banner-Nav-Background-Gray_03.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That works! But it still leaves a small gap above. The approved answer is where the problem is, the css reset had vertical-align:baseline.